# Extract substring between n and m delimiter

Tags: bash, cut

I want to write a for loop to obtain everything between the third `/` to the 4th `.` for a list of files.

My attempt:

```
for mcool_file in ./input/*.mcool; do
    while IFS= read -r id; do
        id | cut -d \\ -f 4- -d_ -f1-4
        # Do something
    done;
done
```

Traceback:

```
cut: only one type of list may be specified
```

Input

```
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
./../input/A001C008.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
```

Desired output

```
A001C007
A001C008
```

Comment: if we can assume the files are roughly that format, then this could perhaps be restated as "from the third `/` to the first `.` after it". Or "from the last `/`", if you just want the filename part of the full path regardless of how long the path is. The way you put it now, something like `./a.b/c/x.y.z` would give `x.y` and we'd need to count the dots that get removed from the left to know where to cut on the right.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
for pathname in input/*.mcool; do
    basename "${pathname%%.*}"
done
```

This iterates over all names in the directory `input` that end in `.mcool`.  For each pathname in `$pathname`, the pathname is truncated at the first dot using the standard parameter substitution `${pathname%%.*}` (removes the longest suffix string matching the pattern `.*` from the value of `$pathname`), and then `basename` is used for extracting the filename portion of the pathname.

Testing:

```bash
$ tree
.
`-- input
    |-- A001C001.something.mcool
    |-- A001C002.something.mcool
    |-- A001C003.something.mcool
    |-- A001C004.something.mcool
    |-- A001C005.something.mcool
    |-- A001C006.something.mcool
    |-- A001C007.something.mcool
    |-- A001C008.something.mcool
    `-- A001C009.something.mcool

2 directories, 9 files
```

```bash
$ for pathname in input/*.mcool; do basename "${pathname%%.*}"; done
A001C001
A001C002
A001C003
A001C004
A001C005
A001C006
A001C007
A001C008
A001C009
```

This assumes that the first dot in `$pathname` occurs in the filename and not in the directory part of the pathname, which is why I don't start the pattern with `./`.

But we can turn it around to allow for dots in the directory path too, by calling `basename` first:

```bash
for pathname in ./input/*.mcool; do
    name=$(basename "$pathname")
    printf '%s\n' "${name%%.*}"
done
```

If we *know* that that the suffix string we want to remove is exactly the string `.something.mcool` (or `.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool` in your case), then the best solution would probably be something like

```bash
for pathname in ./input/*.something.mcool; do
    basename "$pathname" .something.mcool
done
```

... which uses `basename` to remove the known suffix from the pathname and return the filename portion of the pathname in one go, one pathname at a time.

With implementations of `basename` that support the non-standard `-a` and `-s` options (for handling multiple files and removing a fixed suffix string from each), you could even get away without using a loop at all, if there are not too many files to process:

```bash
$ basename -a -s .something.mcool ./input/*.something.mcool
A001C001
A001C002
A001C003
A001C004
A001C005
A001C006
A001C007
A001C008
A001C009
```

See the `basename(1)` manual on your system.

Comment: `-a` and `-s`  are non-standard extensions, but that  doesn't make the `basename` implementations that  support them non-standard.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. Sloppy use of words. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- input/*.mcool(N:t:r:r:r:r)
```

(where the `:t` modifier gets you the *tail*, and `:r` the *root* (removes an extension) of the file like in csh or vim).

Or:

```
set -o histsubstpattern
print -rC1 -- input/*.mcool(N:t:s/.*//)
```

Or:

```
(){print -rC1 -- ${@/.*}} input/*.mcool(N:t)
```

(using ksh-style `${var/pattern[/replacement]}` instead of csh-style `:s/foo/bar/`, here on the arguments passed to an anonymous function, see also `${@%%.*}` also from ksh).

Answer (score 0):

If all input looks like

```
./../input/A001C007.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
```

then the probably easiest approach is:

```
start cmd:> sed -e 's+^./../input/++' -e 's/\..*$//' input
A001C007
A001C008
```

If you want everything including the third `/` be deleted and everything from the next `.` then

```
start cmd:> sed -r -e 's+^([^/]*/){3}++' -e 's/\..*$//' input
A001C007
A001C008
```

A general solution as you described it would have to count the number of `.` up to the third `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it is the third `/`and fourth `.`, you may as well use `awk` and define fields according to `/` and `.` as delimiters:

```
awk -F'[./]' '{print $7}'
```

Comment: This works for the input given, when the delimiters are always in the order `./..//.`. But if the input has slashes and dots in another sequence, it's not true that it's always the seventh field between the third `/` and fourth `.`.